# Pandas: Referring to previous calculation results within the same calculation step

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame and want to calculate a new column based on values of the current row and the previous one.
The following, where I just add the current value and the previous value, example works fine:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[1,2,3,4,5], columns=["old"])
df.loc[:, ["new"]] = df["old"] + df["old"].shift()
df
```

[image]

However, when I try to use a previous value of the new column for the calculation of further values of the new column, this only works for calculations that refer to values of the new column that exist before the calculation started:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[1,2,3,4,5], columns=["old"])
df.loc[0, ["new"]] = 0
df.loc[1:, ["new"]] = df["old"] + df["new"].shift()
df
```

[image]

As you can see, it is able to calculate the value of the second row, since I defined the value of `"new"` for the first row manually, but it is not able to refer to the result of the second row when calculating values for the third row and onwards.

How can I achieve this in the most elegant and efficient way? Basically, I am looking for a more elegant and efficient way of this:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[1,2,3,4,5], columns=["old"])
df.loc[0, ["new"]] = 0

for i in range(1, len(df)):
    df.loc[i:, ["new"]] = df["old"] + df["new"].shift()
```

This results in the correct output, but I think the loop is kind of inefficient.

[image]

Comment: If this is about addition specifically there is the method `cumsum`.

Comment: unfortunately not, it's just a simplified version of a real-life problem

Answer (score 0):

What your looking for is pandas cumsum (cumulative sum)

```
df['new'] = df['old'].cumsum()
```

The only difference will be that you for some reason want to the first row to be zero.

You will have to change that manually after the cumsum